# jQuery animation setup callback throws error

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate

I want to implement a jQuery animation callback method progress or step,

but in either case I'm getting the following error:

```
NS_ERROR_IN_PROGRESS: Component returned failure code: 0x804b000f (NS_ERROR_IN_PROGRESS) [nsICacheEntry.dataSize]
```

I searched a lot but not able to find anything in context, I am kind of stuck here, please suggest what could cause this error?

**In fiddle i tried with step and progress and its working there , but not able to get it worked in my code, I am just looking, has some one faced such kind of error in jquery animation?**

The sample code is:

```
    this.taskHandle.find('img').stop(true, true).animate({
        //todo//
        top: vtop, // this.taskHandle.outerHeight(),
        //'top': 0 - $('.target.upper').height(),
        width: 0,
        opacity: 0
    }, {
        duration: 2000,
        step: function(){
            console.log('I am called');
        }
    },

    $.proxy(function() {
        // some css clearing method
    }, {
        // some further actions after animation completes
    })
);
```

Comment: Which jQuery version do you use in your production environment?

Comment: According to the error-message and some snooping around in the sourcecode of Firefox, this is an issue with a cached item, that hasn't finished loading/being written. Nothing in the posted code suggests you are using any resources that might not have been loaded, so I think we will be hard pressed to help you any further unless we get to see a little more of the code.

Comment: Is this an iOS application?

Comment: no. .net application

Answer (score 3):

You have some semantic errors going on here. I'm going to repost your code, formatted for easier reading:

```
this.taskHandle.find('img')
    .stop(true, true)
    .animate(
        {
            //todo//
            top:  vtop , // this.taskHandle.outerHeight(),
            //'top' : 0 - $('.target.upper').height(),
            width : 0,
            opacity : 0
        },
        {
            duration:2000,
            step: function() {
                console.log('I am called');
            }
        },
        $.proxy(
            function() {
                // some css clearing method
            },
            {
                // some further actions after animation completes
            }
        )
    );
```

First: `animate()` doesn't accept 3 parameters (at least not those 3 parameters). I'm not sure what you are trying to do with your `css clearing method`, but anything you wan't to happen after the animation is complete should be in the `complete` method that you add right next to the `step` method.

Second: `$.proxy()` needs to have the context in which you want it to run as the second parameter, not some other"complete"-function.

So here is a slightly modified example which works. You can try it yourself in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/26Lam79a/).

```
var vtop = 100;

$('div')
    .stop(true, true)
    .animate(
        {
            top:  vtop,
            width: 0,
            opacity : 0
        },
        {
            duration: 2000,
            step: function() {
                console.log('I am called');
            },
            complete: function () {
                alert('complete');// some further actions after animation completes
            }
        }
    );
```

Comment: The code above is the running code, so i cannot remove the $.proxy(), $.proxy() is just to clear all styles of target caused by animation like resetting it to its original width,top etc. and thats is executing fine, only change i have made here to use the step or progress callback.

Comment: Ok. If it works, then by all means, use it as is. Anyway, the error codes that you mention in your question don't look like JavaScript errors to me. Are you sure that your problem isn't somewhere else?

Comment: The thing is i had to manipulate animations effect as the target animated that's why i need to use step or progress, but as soon as i write step or progress callback method it throws me this error and even it dint catch callback method block,

Comment: Can you try removing the third parameter to `animate()` (the `$.proxy()`-part), just for testing. Right now you are using some kind of mix of the allowed parameters, and I'm thinking that it only worked before because the only property on your options-object was `duration`, and when you add `step` it breaks.

Comment: The error you are getting "NS_ERROR..." is maybe caused by a popup blocker and I guess you are testing your code on firefox :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use Julian Shapiro's **[Velocity.js](http://julian.com/research/velocity/)**, which animations are (arguable) faster than jQuery and CSS ([read this](http://davidwalsh.name/css-js-animation) for more)

It allows you to use callbacks such as :

- begin
- progress
- complete

like :

```
var vtop = 100;
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('div').find("img").velocity({
        top: vtop,
        width: 0,
        opacity: 0
    }, {
        duration: 2000,
        begin: function (elements) {
            console.log('begin');
        },
        progress: function (elements, percentComplete, timeRemaining, timeStart) {
            $("#log").html("<p>Progress: " + (percentComplete * 100) + "% - " + timeRemaining + "ms remaining!</p>");
        },
        complete: function (elements) {
            // some further actions after animation completes
            console.log('completed');
            $.proxy( ... ); // some css clearing method
        }
    });
}); // ready
```

**Notice** that you just need to replace `.animate()` by `.velocity()`

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/m5w7a54a/)**